# docker not working after update

Tags: docker, fedora, systemd, cgroups

I updated fedora server 23 to fedora server 25. Everything works fine execpt docker. which is quite bad because i have about 28 containers that should be running right now. I have found out that it could be a problem with `SystemD` and how the `cgroups` filesystems get mounted. So i added

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="systemd.legacy_systemd_cgroup_controller=yes"
```

but it is still not working. In my system logfile i can see some more errors

```
Jan 30 08:23:50 kindred.one systemd[1]: libcontainer-7475-systemd-test-default-dependencies.scope: Scope has no PIDs. Refusing.
Jan 30 08:23:50 kindred.one systemd[1]: libcontainer-7475-systemd-test-default-dependencies.scope: Scope has no PIDs. Refusing.
```

but i haven't found anything useful about this error.

this is the error that i get on the terminal.

```
/usr/bin/docker-current: Error response from daemon: invalid header field value "oci runtime error: container_linux.go:247: starting container process caused \"process_linux.go:334: running prestart hook 1 caused \\\"error running hook: exit status 1, stdout: , stderr: \\\"\"\n".
```

EDIT:

these are the labels on the docker binaries

```
system_u:object_r:container_runtime_exec_t:s0
```

Comment: If enabled, try disabling SELinux.

Comment: Thnx. It works again. But i am not quite happy with disabling SELinux. On my laptop it works with selinux enabled

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems related to SELinux labelling.
If you don't want to disable SELinux, you have to relabelling your system.

Check the output of

```
ls -Z1 /usr/bin/docker*
```

They should be

```
system_u:object_r:docker_exec_t:s0
```

It seems you get the same than [Bug 1405131 - Docker refuses to start containers (SELINUX)](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1405131).

Comment: because thats what i already did. and the SELinux labels seem to be correct. I edited the question and added the selinux labels